# Is grouping parallelised in data.table 1.12.0?

Tags: r, data.table, openmp

In the changelog of `data.table v1.12.0` I noticed the following:

> Subsetting, ordering and grouping now use more parallelism

I tested if I could speed-up some grouping but without any success. I made several different tests and I always get identical results. Is grouping actually parallelised? Maybe I do not properly use the thread options? As you can see `data.table` has been compiled with `openmp` otherwise `setDTthread` print a message to tell the user that there is no support of `openmp`. Here a reproducile example of one of my tests.

```
library(data.table)

n = 5e6
k = 1e4

DT = data.table(x = runif(n), y = runif(n), grp = sample(1:k, n, TRUE))

# Any function not too fast
f = function(x,y) as.list(eigen(cov(cbind(x,y)), only.values = TRUE)$value)

setDTthreads(1)
getDTthreads()
#> [1] 1

system.time(DT[ , f(x,y), by = grp])
#> utilisateur     système      écoulé 
#>       3.365       0.008       3.374

setDTthreads(0)
getDTthreads(T)
#> omp_get_max_threads() = 4
#> omp_get_thread_limit() = 2147483647
#> DTthreads = 0
#> RestoreAfterFork = true
#> [1] 4

system.time(DT[ , f(x,y), by = grp])
#> utilisateur     système      écoulé 
#>       3.324       0.029       3.238
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Yes, grouping is parallelized in v 1.12.0**

Your benchmark is a bit of a red herring. You want a *fast* `f(x, y)` if you want to isolate the speed of grouping. Using the cardinalities of your examples but with a trivial function we get:

```r
library(data.table)
  packageVersion("data.table")
#> [1] '1.12.0'

n = 5e6
N <- n
k = 1e4

print(getDTthreads())
#> [1] 12

DT = data.table(x = rep_len(runif(n), N),
                y = rep_len(runif(n), N),
                grp = rep_len(sample(1:k, n, TRUE), N))
bench::system_time(DT[, .(a = 1L), by = "grp"])
#>   process      real 
#> 250.000ms  72.029ms

setDTthreads(1)

bench::system_time(DT[, .(a = 1L), by = "grp"])
#>   process      real 
#> 125.000ms 126.385ms
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

That is, we were slightly faster in the parallel case, but only by about 50 ms -- negligible compared to the 3 s of your function.

If we bump out the size of the DT, we can see a more dramatic difference:

```r
library(data.table)
  packageVersion("data.table")
#> [1] '1.12.0'

n = 5e6
N <- 1e9
k = 1e4

print(getDTthreads())
#> [1] 12

DT = data.table(x = rep_len(runif(n), N),
                y = rep_len(runif(n), N),
                grp = rep_len(sample(1:k, n, TRUE), N))
bench::system_time(DT[, .(a = 1L), by = "grp"])
#> process    real 
#> 45.719s 14.485s

setDTthreads(1)

bench::system_time(DT[, .(a = 1L), by = "grp"])
#> process    real 
#> 24.859s 24.890s
```

```r
sessioninfo::session_info()
#> - Session info ----------------------------------------------------------
#>  setting  value                       
#>  version  R version 3.5.2 (2018-12-20)
#>  os       Windows 10 x64              
#>  system   x86_64, mingw32             
#>  ui       RTerm                       
#>  language (EN)                        
#>  collate  English_Australia.1252      
#>  ctype    English_Australia.1252      
#>  tz       Australia/Sydney            
#>  date     2019-02-01                  
#>
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok so if I understand your answer, what is parallelized if the computation of the group i.e. how many groups, which rows and so on. But not the computation of aggregation itself i.e. the loop over each group. Is that correct?

Comment: Essentially, yes. The grouping, not necessarily the computation within each group, is parallelized.

Answer (score 1):

Here an answer not validated by any authority (e.g. a member of `data.table` team) based on my exploration of the `data.table` issues from the github repository.

From issue [#3042](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3042) I understand that `sum` and `mean` are optimized. We can benchmark it to verify that it is correct:

```
library(data.table)
n = 1e7 ; k = 1e5
DT = data.table(x = runif(n), y = runif(n), grp = sample(1:k, n, TRUE))

setDTthreads(1)
system.time(DT[ , mean(x), by = grp]) #> 0.8 s
setDTthreads(0)
system.time(DT[ , mean(x), by = grp]) #> 0.4 s
```

However Matt Dowle in the same issue [#3042](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3042) wrote:

> There is much left to do on extending to other gforce functions and grouping arbitrary functions

And in [#3130](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/3130) sritchie73 wrote

> Worth noting here that R functions are inherently not thread safe, e.g. so they can't be passed to multithreaded C++ code via Rcpp.

So, it seems that parallelization of user-defined functions is not a simple task and there is no current implementation in `data.table`.